# How to find occurences of same subsequent characters in a string with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

How can I find occurences of same subsequent characters in a string with a regular expression or function?

Example:

> I am l​**ee**​t and I have a thr​**ee**​ pi​**zz**​as. That n​**oo**​b right there has only one pi​**zz**​a. P​**oo**​r boy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex):

```
/(.)\1/
```

Change `\1` to `\1+` if you want to find sequences of length two or more.

Note that the syntax can vary depending on the regular expression engine you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of regex you're working with, but for `egrep`, this works:

```
egrep '(.)\1' < file
```

That will show all lines that have two of some character in a row. If you want just letters:

```
egrep `([A-Za-z])\1' < file
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this in a perl flavour. `\w` matches a word character, and `\2` matches second parentheses.

```
m/((\w)\2+)/g
```

Comment: Why do you need the first capture group?

Comment: @sln: I use it to get all consecutive letters as the first group (`$1` or `\1`). I could have avoided it.

Comment: Well, Perlish `$&` might slow it down; if used in a while(m/(())/g) its probably better, but @ary = m/(())/g might store extra data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work ................  `(.)\1+`